# Backslash in vs code terminal not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard, character

I recently set up vs code on a newly installed Ubuntu 22.04, which I am accessing via remote desktop connection from Windows.
I am now experiencing that a backslash character cannot be typed inside the internal terminal, but everywhere else (settings, text editor, ...). Also other level-3 characters such as {[]} are just working fine in the terminal and in other windows.
Keyboard layout is German, so the keybinding is "Alt Gr + ß".

I already tried the instructions given in the respective github and SO issues, which did not resolve it. And of course I searched the keyboard shortcuts for anything just remotely related. Also I changed from a VM also with Ubuntu22.04 with the exact same VScode setup (export via github), where everything just works fine.

The follwing is the output of vscode's "Keyboard Shortcut Troubleshooting":

```bash
# first pressing ctrl + shift + P to open Keyboard Shortcut Troubleshooting, then pressing Alt Gr + ß for backslash
2023-07-24 16:22:26.824 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2023-07-24 16:22:26.825 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
2023-07-24 16:22:26.825 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control
2023-07-24 16:22:26.826 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
2023-07-24 16:22:26.826 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
2023-07-24 16:22:27.232 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2023-07-24 16:22:27.233 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
2023-07-24 16:22:27.233 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,shift], code: ShiftLeft, keyCode: 16, key: Shift
2023-07-24 16:22:27.234 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,shift], code: ShiftLeft, keyCode: 4 ('Shift')
2023-07-24 16:22:27.234 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
2023-07-24 16:22:27.518 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2023-07-24 16:22:27.519 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving ctrl+shift+P
2023-07-24 16:22:27.519 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 2 keybinding entries, matched workbench.action.showCommands, when: no when condition, source: built-in.
2023-07-24 16:22:27.519 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,shift], code: KeyP, keyCode: 80, key: P
2023-07-24 16:22:27.519 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,shift], code: KeyP, keyCode: 46 ('P')
2023-07-24 16:22:27.520 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving ctrl+shift+P
2023-07-24 16:22:27.520 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 2 keybinding entries, matched workbench.action.showCommands, when: no when condition, source: built-in.
2023-07-24 16:22:27.520 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Invoking command workbench.action.showCommands.
2023-07-24 16:22:28.198 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Ignoring single modifier shift due to it being pressed together with other keys.
# Here starts the backslash part
2023-07-24 16:23:05.481 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2023-07-24 16:23:05.482 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
2023-07-24 16:23:05.482 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [], code: ArrowLeft, keyCode: 225, key: AltGraph
2023-07-24 16:23:05.482 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [], code: ArrowLeft, keyCode: 0 ('unknown')
2023-07-24 16:23:05.482 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
2023-07-24 16:23:05.695 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2023-07-24 16:23:05.695 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving [
2023-07-24 16:23:05.710 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ No keybinding entries.
# in the next line you can see that the \ key is indeed recognized
2023-07-24 16:23:05.710 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [], code: Minus, keyCode: 219, key: \
2023-07-24 16:23:05.710 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [], code: Minus, keyCode: 92 ('[')
2023-07-24 16:23:05.710 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving [
2023-07-24 16:23:05.711 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ No keybinding entries.
# only pressing ß
2023-07-24 16:25:49.559 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2023-07-24 16:25:49.626 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving [
2023-07-24 16:25:49.626 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ No keybinding entries.
2023-07-24 16:25:49.626 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [], code: Minus, keyCode: 219, key: ß
2023-07-24 16:25:49.626 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [], code: Minus, keyCode: 92 ('[')
2023-07-24 16:25:49.626 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving [
2023-07-24 16:25:49.626 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ No keybinding entries.
```

Anybody any ideas?

#### Update:

I just tried an external bash terminal and encountered the same problem there. So I start to think that it is somehow connected to rdp + terminal configuration.

Comment: anything here help? (esp the section on remote connection to Linux) https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues#troubleshoot-linux-keybindings

Comment: thanks for this hint, but the setting was already on keyCode. Didn't find anything else helpful.

Comment: I just found a workaround or part of the solution maybe: When I press the insert button and then the usual keybinding Alt Gr + ß, it works. Its annoying but will work for now I guess... I'll leave the question open if anybody still has another idea